# How to solve with Python a non-linear system of differential equation at order 2?

Tags: numerical-methods

I need to solve the following equation with Python :
\begin{align}
r''&=f_{1}(r,r',\theta, \theta',\phi,\phi')
\\
\theta''&=f_{2}(r,r',\theta,\theta',\phi,\phi')
\\
\phi''&=f_{3}(r,r',\theta,\theta',\phi,\phi')
\end{align}
$f_{1},f_{2},f_{3}$  are non-linear (including trigonometric functions, exponential etc..)
i tried to use the function `odeint` from `scipy.integrate`, but it requires a function at first argument and i don't know how to build it.

I have build the following fonction but it doesn't seem to be correct.
[image: I have build the following fonction but it doesn't seem to be correct]

It takes in entry the 6 arguments of $(r,r',\theta, \theta',\phi,\phi')$ and ***t*** a numpy.array that contains the number of point that odeint will solve

It returns $(r',r'',\theta', \theta'',\phi',\phi'')$

**Could someone explain me how to build for odeint a function of a system of non linear differential equation at order 2 ? Or point me the fault that contain my python function ?**

Thank you all in advance for your help, I deeply appreciate it.

Comment: Try and reduce them to first order by introducing new variables. For example $y''=-2xy$, let $y'=v$ and $v'=-2xy$

Comment: Think that $r''=f_1(r,r',\cdots)\equiv \dot r_1= r_2,\dot r_2 = f_1(r_1,r_2,\cdots)$

Comment: Remember `odeint` only solves first order systems so this procedure is essential assuming you want the actual function not the first derivative

Comment: Upon inspection, your link seems to be done fine. Is it giving any errors that could be helpful to know about?